# Explanation on Delphi compiler error E2382 Cannot call constructors using instance variables

Tags: delphi, constructor, record

I have this record (BTW it could also be a class, but with records this code makes more sense):

```
interface

type
  TMyRecord = record
    A: Integer;
    constructor Initialize(V: Integer);
    procedure InitOne;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyRecord.Initialize(V: Integer);
begin
  A := V;
end;
```

(implementation of method InitOne omitted for now).

As I know them, record constructors are callable both in a functional form, like conventional constructors for classes, or in a procedural form, directly on a record variable (reference: [Record constructors in Delphi](https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/record-constructors-in-delphi/)).

Giving that, this code compiles and works as expected:

```
procedure DoSomething;
var
  pMyRec: TMyRecord;
begin
  pMyRec.Initialize(1);              // constructor called in procedural form
  pMyRec := TMyRecord.Initialize(1); // constructor called in functional form
end;
```

While this implementation of InitOne doesn't:

```
procedure TMyRecord.InitOne;
begin
  Self.Initialize(1);              // constructor called in procedural form <-- E2382
  Self := TMyRecord.Initialize(1); // constructor called in functional form
end;
```

Why? Shouldn't `Self.Initialize(1)` be identical to `pMyRec.Initialize(1)`, both called as a procedure acting on its "instance"?

Comment: Sorry, I obviously have read that question and its answer, but stopped reading when the argument pointed to using a legacy object type (I was using classes and records, not objects). Must have read one line more.

Comment: Anyway, a downvote for a simple duplicate question seems a bit excessive to me.

Comment: I agree. The Delphi subgroup on Stack Overflow seems to be very harsh lately. The other question was indeed about old style objects, although the answer has an NB that it applies to records as well. Apart from that, there is virtually no information about this error. Some unanswered or incorrectly answered questions on other sites, and some site scraper copies of this one question.

Comment: Indeed. When reading questions and answers one have to meet relevancy with time, we can't read all Q/As completely. If I find a question barely relevant and an answer speaking of legacy objects I'm not even aware of, I think it's quite natural being led to asking a new one. Just my opinion.

Comment: Considering the syntax `TMyRecord(Pointer(@Self)^).Initialize(1)` works, I suspect there is no technical reason justifying it and probably is just a glitch in the compiler.

Comment: @KenBourassa by reading the second answer to the duplicated question, it seems that they enforced this for supporting mobile development.